# Windows 10 Bash Shell: Run exe with arguments, return output

Tags: bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**Can you use the bash shell in the Linux subsystem for Windows 10 to run an .exe that is a command-line program and pass arguments to it, as well as to get the output from running the command as if it was run from the Windows command prompt?**

Basically, I have a Windows command-line program that I want to use through the bash shell as if it were within the ubuntu install, but I don't know how to set that up or even if it's possible.

According to [this Microsoft issue](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13284702-let-us-launch-windows-processes-from-bash?page=2&per_page=20), launching Windows processes from Bash has been supported since the Creators Update.  Does that include sending arguments?

**Background**

I'm using Windows 10 with the Ubuntu linux subsystem.

In Windows, I have installed [lando](https://docs.lndo.io/), which is a command-line piece of software that lets you manage web apps through docker.

I want to use the `lando` command through the bash shell because I want to script a bunch of commands in my `.bashrc`.

I can call lando from bash like this:

alias lando='/mnt/c/Program¥ Files/Lando/bin/lando.exe'

When I enter `lando` (no arguments), I get the command line help as I would expect.

However, when I enter a command such as `lando info` in bash, the output (status of running containers) is printed to the screen, but I have to manually stop the command with CTRL+C. (In Windows cmd prompt, when I run `lando info`, it automatically returns me to the command line.)

Moreover, when I run a command like `lando start` from bash (to start up some containers), the output that would normally be printed to the screen (when the command is run from Windows) is not output at all.

Comment: Lando is cross-platform, why haven't you installed it directly on Ubuntu?

Comment: @frennky I already have docker set up on Windows and I was worried that running docker and lando through the linux subsystem would give me headaches trying to test with browsers on Windows.